# Trigger not firing from deal hub

Tags: trigger, quote, cpq

We have shifted our CPQ to deal hub now.

We want to fire a trigger on insertion of Quote(standard).

From anonymous window the apex code works fine. But when quote is inserted through deal hub, the method is not executed.

Can someone help me in identifying how does deal hub work? Specifically - how does it insert a quote in Salesforce so that we can fire a trigger accordingly.

Thanks!

PS: The trigger is  written on before insert.

Comment: Please edit you post to include any code that you want us to look at.

Comment: Its already resolved. Thanks. Used a future method